# Scrolling page with image/text/image

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a newbie working on my first ever app.  I want to have a page with images at the top and bottom and a large block of text in between.  I want everything to scroll vertically.  No matter what I try the emulator stops the app when I access the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Scrollview
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>   
    <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="6dip"
            android:id="@+id/Francis_Top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/fhpaint">
    </ImageView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/help_page_intro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#2E2D2B"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/francisinfo"
            android:padding="2dip">
    </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="6dip"
            android:id="@+id/Francis_Bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/fhp"> 
    </ImageView>  
    </TableRow>             

</TableLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>          
</Scrollview>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Ian

**EDIT: Errors in my log:**

```
02-05 18:44:24.391: I/Process(836): Sending signal. PID: 836 SIG: 9
02-05 18:44:32.041: D/gralloc_goldfish(1098): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-05 18:44:32.151: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 3213K/3332K, paused 45ms, total 49ms
02-05 18:44:32.201: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 3572K/3692K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
02-05 18:44:32.321: I/Choreographer(1098): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 18:44:37.911: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 483K, 16% free 3234K/3812K, paused 106ms, total 121ms
02-05 18:44:37.971: I/dalvikvm-heap(1098): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.503MB for 1334776-byte allocation
02-05 18:44:38.311: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 12% free 4526K/5116K, paused 88ms, total 89ms
02-05 18:44:38.471: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 4585K/5116K, paused 114ms, total 116ms
02-05 18:44:38.471: I/dalvikvm-heap(1098): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.157MB for 635812-byte allocation
02-05 18:44:38.781: D/dalvikvm(1098): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 5206K/5740K, paused 83ms, total 84ms
02-05 18:44:39.461: I/Choreographer(1098): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 18:44:40.741: I/Choreographer(1098): Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 18:44:41.151: I/Choreographer(1098): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-05 18:44:45.811: D/AndroidRuntime(1098): Shutting down VM
02-05 18:44:45.811: W/dalvikvm(1098): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a4fba8)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): Process: com.androidbook.ds1, PID: 1098
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbook.ds1/com.androidbook.ds1.QuizFrancisActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class Scrollview
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class Scrollview
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.androidbook.ds1.QuizFrancisActivity.onCreate(QuizFrancisActivity.java:10)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     ... 11 more
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.Scrollview" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.androidbook.ds1-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.androidbook.ds1-2, /system/lib]]
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
02-05 18:44:45.981: E/AndroidRuntime(1098):     ... 20 more
```

Thank you for responding so quickly! I hope this Log helps.
Ian

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: Can you please tell us if you are receiving anything in the LogCat view. If we can see more about your error, we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: I think you can vastly simplify you layout using a LinearLayout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/fhpaint"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/francisinfo"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/fhp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here's an example screen shot:

[image]

Next, you'll need your view controller, known in Android world as a Fragment. Among other lifecycle methods, Fragments usually need to override onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) in order to display their views. For example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    ... other code here ...

    return v;
}
```

Once you've implemented the code above, you should at the very least see the images and the text.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner.  That has done the job!  Thank you very much for helping me.  I really appreciate it as I was stuck at this point for a few days.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help. Also, if my answer proved to be correct, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!